# Merging two methods that read two files to reading one file with one method

Tags: java, refactoring

I am creating a bayesian filter system in Java. At the moment my code learns spam and good text by using separate `.txt` files; `learn.spam("spam.txt");` and `learn.good("good.txt")`.

Both methods are pretty much identical to each other:

```
public void good(String file) throws IOException {
        A2ZFileReader fr = new A2ZFileReader(file);


        String content = fr.getContent();
        String[] tokens = content.split(splitregex);
        int goodTotal = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            String word = tokens[i].toLowerCase();
            Matcher m = wordregex.matcher(word);
            if (m.matches()) {
                goodTotal++;
                if (words.containsKey(word)) {
                    Word w = (Word) words.get(word);
                    w.countGood();
                } else {
                    Word w = new Word(word);
                    w.countGood();
                    words.put(word,w);
                }
            }
        }

public void spam(String file) throws IOException {
    A2ZFileReader fr = new A2ZFileReader(file);

    String content = fr.getContent();
    String[] tokens = content.split(splitregex);
    int spamTotal = 0;//tokenizer.countTokens();

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String word = tokens[i].toLowerCase();
        Matcher m = wordregex.matcher(word);
        if (m.matches()) {
            spamTotal++;
            if (words.containsKey(word)) {
                Word w = (Word) words.get(word);
                w.countBad();
            } else {
                Word w = new Word(word);
                w.countBad();
                words.put(word,w);
            }
        }
    }

    Iterator iterator = words.values().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Word word = (Word) iterator.next();
        word.calcBadProb(spamTotal);
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am trying to fix is that instead of having two `.txt` files I have the following:

```
spam    Gamble tonight only for a cheap price of $5 per hand.

ham     Sex, I love it. I need it now.

ham     yeah I know, I am going tonight that that place, ;) Come join me. You know you want to

ham     It is pretty expensive, just this and that for only ($900)

spam    Call 123123123 to use for free porn
```

The messages are only one per line, spam messages start with spam and good messages start with ham with one tab.
How can I change the methods so that I can train it using only one method and one `.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `good` method to this:

```
public void good(String content) {
    String[] tokens = content.split(splitregex);
    int goodTotal = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String word = tokens[i].toLowerCase();
        Matcher m = wordregex.matcher(word);
        if (m.matches()) {
            goodTotal++;
            if (words.containsKey(word)) {
                Word w = (Word) words.get(word);
                w.countGood();
            } else {
                Word w = new Word(word);
                w.countGood();
                words.put(word,w);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do almost the exact same thing to `spam`.

Then write a method `train` that reads the file, splits it into lines, and then calls the right method based on the first word in each line.

After that, it is trivial to merge everything into one method.

Comment: The variable `word` won't be available?

Comment: Sorry, I missed one line of code when copying. Added it in now.